# Chrome Extension: require.js is not loading modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, requirejs

I'm trying to load the [sentiment module](https://github.com/thisandagain/sentiment), using [require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#requirejs) in my content.js as explained [in this doc](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded):

```
require(['./require', '../node_modules/sentiment'], function (require) {
    //sentiment is now loaded.
    var sentiment = require('../node_modules/sentiment');
    if (sentiment) { 
        console.log('sentiment module loaded'); 
    }
});
```

There are no console errors, so I'm not entirely sure why nothing is being printed to the console or how to fix this issue.

EDIT:
here's my manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "CA-extension",
  "version": "2.0",

  "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "views/popup.html",
    "default_title": "CA-extension"
  },

  "options_page": "views/options.html",

  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "scripts/background.js"
    ]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
    "https://www.reddit.com/r/design_critiques/*"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "js": [
        "scripts/require.js",
        "scripts/content.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "stylesheets/content.css"
      ]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "https://www.reddit.com/r/design_critiques/*"
  ],

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "views/options.html",
    "https://www.reddit.com/r/design_critiques/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Show your manifest.json

Comment: @elegant-user added my manifest above.

Comment: You have added `https://www.reddit.com/r/design_critiques/*` in the `permissions` so your extension will only work for that url. Is this the case?

Comment: yes. that's correct.

Comment: The node module your trying to require won't get loaded because it is not injected as content script.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I'm not sure how to do that. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Its simple. If you want to `reqiure` sentiment using your content script it must be injected in DOM first. Like you injecting  `"scripts/require.js","scripts/content.js"`. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes! and it works. Thank you.